# pinging multi sub nets and saving in external file using bash / linux

Tags: bash

Trying to create a script to ping multiple sub nets, 
but script do not seems to be working correctly,
it seems I'm missing somthing
any help would be appreciated

function to ping and filter:

```
ping_hosts() {
  ping -c 1 $1 > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e "server $1 is online"
  echo $1 >> live_ser_list
 fi
}
```

lop to submit IP's to filter:

```
for i in '192.168.0.' '10.0.0.' '10.0.1.' '192.168.1.';do
echo "starting $i"0" network"
   for j in $i{1..254};
   do
    ping_hosts $j & disown
   done
done
```

edited
did try `$1` and `$j`
The list file is not getting created...

Comment: change this line `ping_hosts $1 & disown` to `ping_hosts $j & disown`

Comment: Nope, it isn't that easy :) ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some errors in your script, here's an improved version. Note the quotes around all variables etc.

```
ping_hosts() {
    local addr="$1"
    if ping -c 1 "${addr}" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "server ${addr} is online"
        echo "${addr}" >> live_ser_list
    fi
}

subnets=("192.168.0." "10.0.0." "10.0.1." "192.168.1.")

for subnet in "${subnets[@]}"; do
    echo "starting ${subnet}0 network"
    for octet in {1..254}; do
        ping_hosts "${subnet}${octet}" & disown
   done
done
```